# How to save Contact Us form data in to existing Customer table of magento database?

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I **want to save contact us form data in to existing customer table** and this means that data are save in those table where after creation of customer account data are saved.

And after saving data in to database there **need to display column of non-register customer** for those customer who have register through contact us form.

Anybody knows answer please share.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212396/store-magento-contact-form-data-in-database and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/adding-a-custom-function-to-insert-contact-forms-to-database-after-post-action-f

Comment: i dont want to save this data in custom table. but need to save in existing customer table

Comment: need to save contact us form data in to existing customer table

Comment: Do you just want `insert` in customer table or `insert` and `update` ? What is your aim behind this save ?